# How to send end-of-stream character with node ipc?

Tags: node.js, ipc, named-pipes

I'm trying to end a IPC stream from my node app. I can't seem to figure out which character represents end-of-stream though and my stream never finishes.

```
const net = require("net");

const server = net.createServer((stream) => {
  console.log("Server: on connection");

  stream.on("data", (buffer) => {
    console.log("Got data:", buffer.toString());

    stream.write("This message ends here ->.");
});

  stream.on("end", () => {
    console.log("Stream ended");
    server.close();
  });
});

server.listen("\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe", () => {
  console.log("Listening...");
});
```

I have tried to add a null character (\u0000) to the end of my message and check for that on the receiving end, but that feels a bit hacky. Is there a way to send something like a end-of-stream character(s)?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a protocol. Your `\u0000` won't work, what if this is actually a valid value in the stream? For example you can use framing. Instead of sending raw bytes, you prefix each message with say 4 bytes representing the data length and then add the message. This is your frame which you then send. That way receiver knows how many bytes he has to read until the end of the content. There are multiple other approaches.

Comment: That being said, if you can guarantee that `\u0000` never appears inside your stream then this is a protocol that will do. Although may not be future-proof.

Comment: I'm 100% sure there will never be a `\u0000` in the message except for where I want it to be, since I control both ends of the pipe. So I guess the easy way is to go with null byte even though it doesn't feel quite right...